# Netgear N600 Wifi Adapter problem on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04

I have just purchased Netgear N600 Wifi Adapter and I have followed through the steps mentioned on the askubuntu forums. I have installed ndiswrapper and configured the driver(bcmn43xx64). The problem I have now is I am unable to see the device when I try the iwconfig or ifconfig command.
Please check the following command and its output:

```
    shashank@sabbath:~$ ndiswrapper -l
    bcmn43xx64 : driver installed
```

And dmesg gives the following output:

```
    shashank@sabbath:~$ dmesg | grep ndis
    [   86.416885] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
    [   86.418843] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
    [   86.447063] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
    [  716.591974] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
    [  716.618683] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
    [  716.623466] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
    [  813.298854] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
    [  830.378697] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
    [  830.383890] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
    [ 2310.365801] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
    [ 2310.398037] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
    [ 2310.402873] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

I have spent hours in solving this by following the Ubuntu Forums and I couldn't find this specific issue addressed anywhere. Could any one please help me in resolving this.
Thank You!